# Php query using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a webpage in which, when the user checks a checkbox, calling a PHP function to query the table if the user exists. If so, it then displays the button to go to next page.

So far I've tried this. I am sure that my php is working fine I checked my result variable returns 0 when user exists, but for some reason it is not executing the `if` statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#submit').hide();
    $('#mobiletask').change(function(){

        if($('#mobiletask').attr('checked'))
        {
            check_availability();
            // $( "#notifyresult" ).html( "<p>Awesome, we'll send you an email!</p>" );
        }
    });
});


//function to check username availability  
function check_availability(){  

    //get the username  
    // var username = $('#username').val();  
    var username = '<?php  echo $_GET['id']; ?>';

    $.post("check_username.php", { username: username }, function(result){  

        //if the result is 1 
        if(result == 1){  

            //show that the username is available  
            $("#errormessage").html('<p>PLease complete the task before proceeding</p>'); 
        }
        else if(result == 0) {  
            //show that the username is NOT available 
            $('#submit').show();
        } 
    });  
}
```

`checkusername.php`

```
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);  

     //mysql query to select field username if it's equal to the username that we check '  
      $result = mysql_query('select studentId from smartphone_scores where studentId = "'. $username      .'"');  

//if number of rows fields is bigger them 0 that means it's NOT available '  
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){  
    //and we send 0 to the ajax request  
    echo 0;  
}else{  
    //else if it's not bigger then 0, then it's available '  
    //and we send 1 to the ajax request  
    echo 1;  
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error, its just not executing my if and else condition.

Comment: Please guide me i am new to ajax and jquery trying to learn

Comment: What you are echoing in `check_username.php`?

Comment: when i alert(result) it displays <html><body>1</body></html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response you are getting:

```
<html><body>1</body></html>
```

What you have to do is to work on your **PHP** file and make sure to remove any HTML in it.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to do it. i tried htmlspecialchars but no luck

Comment: Make sure you don't have **HTML** code in your **PHP** target page. You could have this for example: `<html><body><?php [your code] ?></body></html>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.post("check_username.php", { username: username }, function(result){  

    //if the result is 1 
    if(result == '1'){  

        //show that the username is available  
        $("#errormessage").html('<p>PLease complete the task before proceeding</p>'); 
    }
    else if(result == '0') {  
        //show that the username is NOT available 
        $('#submit').show();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

   $('#submit').hide();    

   $('#mobiletask').on('change',function() {

       if($('#mobiletask').attr('checked'))
       {
          check_availability();
          //$( "#notifyresult" ).html( "<p>Awesome, we'll send you an email!</p>" );
        }
    });

function check_availability() 
{

   //get the username  
   // var username = $('#username').val();  
   var username = '<?php  echo $_GET['id']; ?>';

   $.ajax({
     url: 'check_username.php',
     type: 'POST',
     async: false,
     data: {'name':'username','value':username},
     success: function(result)
     {  
            alert(result);
            //if the result is 1 
            if(result == '1')
            { 
                //show that the username is available  
                $("#errormessage").html('<p>PLease complete the task before proceeding</p>'); 

            }else if(result == '0') 
             {  
                //show that the username is NOT available 
                $('#submit').show();               
              } 
      }, error: function(error)
      {
        alert(error);
      }
    });
   }
 });
```

** Remove the alerts when done with testing the code. **

Comment: Thank you so much, but its the same issue if and else doesnt execute. please help